# ImageView onClick is not working FragmentActivity

Tags: android

May be it is so easy but do not know i have tried so much but it's not working :(

I have layout like this way

[image]

And i have following java code

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{
private ImageView ivMainMenu;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ivMainMenu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivMainMenu);
    ivMainMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("showSlider clicked");
        }
    });
}
```

i have tried

```
 android:clickable="true"
```

but still not working

below is my xml code

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlMainHeader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/header_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHeaderText"
        style="@style/header_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtScore"
        style="@style/black_large"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/extra_small"
        android:background="@drawable/keyboard_btn"
        android:padding="@dimen/extra_small"
        android:text="@string/finish"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_text_color"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivMainMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/menu" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rlMainHeader"
    android:background="@color/main_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llMainSlider"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <include
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/slider" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/dark_text_color"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

in my logcat i am getting following message whenever i click on imageview

```
    04-27 11:09:42.996: V/Provider/Settings(1018):  from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
```

also i want to let you know that if i load any fragment in flMain, in that fragment all event is working fine but not on main layout :( also in llMainSlider noting was happening :(

Comment: Did you set the the clickable property to be true in the XML declaration?

Comment: @liangricha  let me try!

Comment: No, by default ImageView is clickable

Comment: Can you post your layout xml. Could be some other view is overlapping it

Comment: @liangricha I have tried but still not working

Comment: @Libin i have updated xml

Comment: In the layout image you have provided above, the ivMainMenu has a warning icon being displayed in left-down corner. Check what that warning is. It maybe related to your problem.

Comment: @VikramSingh it's nothing just [Accessibility] Missing contentDescription attribute on image

Comment: i don't see any issue in layout. It works on my device.

Comment: This layout is *activity_main.xml*, isn't it? Did you try the same *OnClickListener* method with another view as *tvHeaderText*?

Comment: @Libin don't know but i have tried it so much time in logcat i am getting some data which is i have updated in my question

Comment: Try to debug and set a break point in onClick to try to display some Tost message :)

Comment: @Libin look my actual code is so much long so may be i have to post all the code

Comment: @Libin for just easy to understand for all people i have remove unnecessary things

Comment: @Fllo i have included the slider layout also in that also no click event is working, and in flMain layout which is FrameLayout in that if any fragment i load in that all click event is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try declaring the event on the XML?
It is as simple as this

```
    android:id="@+id/ivMainMenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:onClick="myNewMethod" <!--add this extra line!--->
    android:src="@drawable/menu" />
```

and simply on your Main activity add the `myNewMethod` as am extra function like this

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{
private ImageView ivMainMenu;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
public void myNewMethod(View v) {
      System.out.println("showSlider clicked");
}
```

Good Luck ;)